# How to jump to another view controller after the last page of page view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to make some tutorial pages using page view controller, and I want it to automatically jump to another view controller after the user swipes the last page of the tutorial. I have implemented the `viewControllerAfterViewController` method as follows:

```
if (index==self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count-1) {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHelp" sender:self];
         return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index+1];
```

The problem is, when it comes to the last page, it performs the segue immediately. But I want it to perform the segue after the user swipes the last page. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: There is a delegate method in UIPageViewController delegate that will tell you when the user swipes to a new view controller AFTER the animation completes...but I can't see how your going to get a good experience that way unless the segue is initiated by panning or a button press

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
__weak UIPageViewController* pvcw = pvc;
[pvc setViewControllers:@[page]
              direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
               animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   UIPageViewController* pvcs = pvcw;
                   if (!pvcs) return;
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [pvcs setViewControllers:@[page]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO completion:nil];
                   });
               }];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

                    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[yourViewController class]]) {
                        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                              animated:YES];
                    }
                    else {
                         NSLog(@"Not Found");
                    }
}
```